# from typing_extensions import ParamSpec ImportError: cannot import name 'ParamSpec' from 'typing_extensions'

Tags: fastapi

I was working on FastAPI and this error occured.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn
app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/ping")
async def ping():
    return "Hello, I am alive"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host='localhost', port=8000)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/own_thesis/training/for_api.py", line 2, in <module>
    from fastapi import FastAPI
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\fastapi\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .applications import FastAPI as FastAPI
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\fastapi\applications.py", line 15, in <module>
    from fastapi import routing
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 22, in <module>
    from fastapi.datastructures import Default, DefaultPlaceholder
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\fastapi\datastructures.py", line 3, in <module>
    from starlette.datastructures import URL as URL  # noqa: F401
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\starlette\datastructures.py", line 7, in <module>
    from starlette.concurrency import run_in_threadpool
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\starlette\concurrency.py", line 11, in <module>
    from typing_extensions import ParamSpec
ImportError: cannot import name 'ParamSpec' from 'typing_extensions' (C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\typing_extensions.py)
```

Comment: There's a known issue about this - it will depend on the version you've installed: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/4877 and https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/4868#issuecomment-1119678681

Comment: I uninstalled fastapi and the library typing_extension. Then I installed fastapi without cache (`pip install --no-cache fastapi`) and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 19):

Just making the response from @arunppsg an answer with a small typo correction: you just need to run

```bash
pip uninstall typing_extensions
pip uninstall fastapi
pip install --no-cache fastapi
```

and the problem disappears.

The small typo correction is in `pip uninstall typing_extensions` (with s at the end). Thanks @arunppsg, I couldn't comment on your comment since I still don't have 50 points reputation, and decided to make it an answer. Happy to remove it if you convert your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade typing-extensions using the following:

```
pip install typing_extensions>=4.5 --upgrade
```

This is because `ParamSpec` might require `>=4.5` of `typing-extensions`. Restart your Python kernel after that. This worked for me. I was seeing the same issue with '**override**' as `Cannot import name 'override'`.