# Import scrapy fails because of typing_extensions

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to use the scrapy package in python. I've successfully installed it with pip on a windows machine. The following is the output from pip show

```
Name: Scrapy
Version: 2.7.1
Summary: A high-level Web Crawling and Web Scraping framework
Home-page: https://scrapy.org
Author: Scrapy developers
Author-email: None
License: BSD
Location: c:\tools\anaconda3\envs\ml\lib\site-packages
Requires: Twisted, setuptools, itemloaders, parsel, packaging, cryptography, w3lib, queuelib, lxml, tldextract, PyDispatcher, cssselect, service-identity, itemadapter, protego, pyOpenSSL, zope.interface
Required-by:
```

When I try to import the package, in a Jupyter notebook I get the following error:

```
C:\tools\Anaconda3\envs\ml\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py in <module>
     40 import attr
     41 from incremental import Version
---> 42 from typing_extensions import Literal, ParamSpec, Protocol
     43 
     44 from twisted.internet.interfaces import IDelayedCall, IReactorTime

ImportError: cannot import name 'ParamSpec' from 'typing_extensions' (C:\tools\Anaconda3\envs\ml\lib\site-packages\typing_extensions.py)
```

I've upgraded typing_extensions with no luck. I even followed the steps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73532082/15559280) modifying to fit my issue. What do I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 3.10 or higher you should just be able to `from typing import Literal, ParamSpec, Protocol`.

According to the `typing_extensions` [docs](https://github.com/python/typing_extensions#included-items) those features are part of the standard library.

For example, [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec) is `typing.ParamSpec`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a fresh reset fixed the issue. Came back after having shutdown the computer and it works now...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).